# How to detect DST (whether summer time is active) with scribunto

Tags: date, lua, mediawiki, dst, scribunto

According to the current date, How I could know if it the hour is in summer time in Lua.

For example, the value in France would be actually true *(CEST is currently used)*. During winter it would be false.
Forget is this is too specific: I am just expecting the rules for France. But at this point, I couldn't know if Lua has a native function.

The list of available builtins functions is [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aScribunto/Lua_reference_manual).

Answer (score 7):

The table returned by `os.date("*t", someday)` has a field `isdst` representing if it's daylight saving time.

```
local someday = os.time{year=2013, month=6, day=20}
local t = os.date("*t", someday)
print(t.isdst)
```

Getting the current time is easier, calling `os.time` without arguments will return the current date and time.

```
local now = os.time()
local t = os.date("*t", now)
print(t.isdst)
```

Comment: just a question: how I do for having the someday variable being the current time?

Comment: The problem here is that os.time() would return the time in UTC on the wikimedia's servers.

Answer (score 2):

`os.date("%Z")` returns `"CEST"` if your system is using Central European Summer Time, which is what France is using now. Outside summer time, it returns `"CET"`.

Comment: thanks this short way of doing it. Does it return a string ("CEST" or "CET")? If Yes, I can say that this is exactly that I want my function to output. I wanted something shorter than with #ifeq in wikisyntax.

Comment: Yes, `os.date("%Z")` returns a string.

Comment: It was working on command line, but finally it seems there is a kind of problem: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Wrapper

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other two answers (by @lhf and @Yu Hao) which are right, note that dealing correctly with time is *complicated*. If I were you I would consider using a library for it, such as [Penlight](http://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/classes/pl.Date.html). Note that even Penlight is [not](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/issues/89) [perfect](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/pull/90) but at least people are using it so issues get fixed eventually.

Comment: Thanks you. I am sorry, but i was looking for something working with https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto . I don't have enough privileges to add third party libraries, because I am a simple user of the wiki.

Comment: Then you can just look at https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/62fc78dd0d4834619106797f8978ffdb302cb484/lua/pl/Date.lua for inspiration I guess.

Comment: It was working on command line, but finally it seems there is a kind of problem: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Wrapper